# Filtering data issue in React native

Tags: sorting, react-native, filter, setstate

I am getting response from server, but, I have to display last 5 indexes of data. So, I tried to do with some logic like if indexes is greater than 4, Then do filter. **ReturnsData** has the response.

But, The data is not persistent always, Some times that data is only 1 or 2 indexes, So, my logic getting wrong and UI showing empty, Even I tried to set else condition in react native, But, nothing working.

```
    someAction = () => {
          let lastFiveYearsData = [];
          if (ReturnsData.length > 4) {
            lastFiveYearsData = ReturnsData.sort((a, b) => a.year - b.year);
             filteredArray = lastFiveYearsData.slice(Math.max(lastFiveYearsData.length - 5, 1));
          } else {
            this.filteredArray = ReturnsData;
          }



        filteredArray.map((item, index) => {
            //do some work here
            }
}
    console.log ('filteredArray', filteredArray)
```

**filteredArray** showing undefined
Even I tried with set state which is not working and showing undefined **filteredArray** this is global defined.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` condition you are assigning the data to the `this.filteredArray` instead of `filteredArray`.